# Accessing public field of generic type

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement generic queue in C++ but I have the problem with templates:

The is the queue element `struct`:

```
template<class T>
struct Elem{
    T *obj;
    Elem<T> *sled;
    Elem(T *p){
        obj=p;
        sled=0;
    }
};
```

And this is the `Queue` class:

```
template<class T> class Queue{ 
public:
    //
    // public function go here....
    //

    T* get(ID id){
        for(Elem<T> *tek = head; tek; tek = tek->sled ){
            if(id == tek->obj->id ){ // <--- ERROR: `id` is not member of '<template class>'
                return tek->obj;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


 }
```

Now if I define:

```
Queue<PCB>* myQueue = ....
```

compiler outputs the error:

> `id` is not member of `PCB`

### The question:

Is it possible to access public fields of template classes if all of `T` classes will have that particular field (in this example `id` field)?

Comment: yes, youre template will only work with types that have that public `id` field though, but that's part of its requirement

Comment: That's what I thought as well - `id` field is public but it still breaks :( And currently, I **only** use `Queue` for class `PCB`

Comment: then PCB doesn't have an `id` field.  [look at this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e402150357a79e7c)

Comment: btw this looks really unsafe, why do you have pointers everywhere instead of `Elem` having an object, and why aren't you using an initialization list for the constructor?

Comment: Ah, part of "requirements". This is actually some low-level school project and we are not allowed to use "fancy" staff ;)

Comment: it's not fancy, it's just right.  if you get a pointer and then copy it, how do you know when the object you're pointing to gets destroyed?

Comment: Thanks, for the example. It shows that it should work as you said. My `PCB` class definitely has public `id` but it's type is `ID` which is `typedef int`. This might be the issue here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68927/discussion-between-ryan-haining-and-jovan-perovic).